# SQL Server: Count with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table which follows the state of the item delivery:

```
ID     | ContractID  | State
----------------------------------
1      | 125         | Created
2      | 125         | Activated
3      | 125         | PickupStarted
4      | 125         | PickedUp
5      | 125         | DeliveryStarted
6      | 125         | Delivered
7      | 126         | Created
8      | 126         | Activated
9      | 126         | PickupStarted
10     | 126         | PickedUp
11     | 126         | DeliveryStarted
12     | 126         | Delivered
13     | 127         | Created
14     | 127         | Activated
15     | 127         | PickupStarted
16     | 127         | PickedUp
```

I would like to create SQL query which counts only those 'ContractIds' which are not delivered yet (only those whose current status has reached 'PickedUp' status). In this case that would be 'ContractId' 127.
Is there a way to do that type of COUNT()?

Comment: You could use a (conditional) `COUNT` and a `HAVING`, yes. What was your attempt? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Please feel free to write that SQL command if you know it. I've tried this one, but it doesn't work
'select * from ContractStatus where State in ('Activated','Created', 'PickupStarted', 'PickedUp') and State not in ('Delivered','DeliveryStarted')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select count(distinct contractId)
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.contractId = t.contractid and
                        t2.status not like 'Deliver%'
                 );
```

Or, if you specifically want to get `PickedUp` as the last status:

```
select count(*)
from t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id) from t t2 2here t2.contractid = t.contractid) and
      t.status = 'PickedUp';
```

The two are different.  The second is specifically that the last status is `PickedUp`.  The first is anyone that has not reached a "deliver" status.